# XCode keeps asking me to convert to Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

When I open my multi-project workspace, which uses Cocoapods, XCode asks if I want to convert the syntax to Swift 3. The problem is that I've already done this. I'm able to build my app with the deployment target set to 10.0.

So, why is it continuing to ask this question and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the beta version of Cocoapods: `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Comment: Either way, I still get the message.

Comment: I removed pods and did a pod install

Comment: I rebuilt my whole workspace. Although, I needed to do that for my app's code anyway. Apple says to minimise dynamic libs!

Comment: We ran into a similar situation at work. Xcode would tell a colleague of mine to upgrade to Swift 3 syntax even though the project already was on Swift 3. Turned out I was using CocoaPods 1.1.1 and she was using CocoaPods 1.0.1. After upgrading to 1.1.1, the problem went away for her.